# High Res Model doesn't load in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

We tried to load an Archilogic model in A-Frame, but for some reason it only loads the low resolution one even though the high resolution version should be available.

I copy pasted the link of this Archilogic scene: https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/archilogic/rhvdxunm?modelResourceId=1512c075-3abe-4bf9-8095-0a827771e4b0&mode=edit&view-menu=none&main-menu=interior&logo=false
into the scene text box of the https://appcreator.3d.io app creator. However only the low resolution version shows up. My suspicion is that the app creator somehow extracts the wrong bake id?

This is the entity that gets created by the editor:

```html
<a-entity id="apartment" io3d-data3d="key:535e624259ee6b0200000484/processing/2017-08-29_12-12-55_9GT5qQ/lighting.gz.data3d.buffer" shadow="receive:true; cast:false"></a-entity>
```

Comment: have you tried saving your original model before using it in the app creator?

Comment: Hm... I think that was the solution... Could it be that there is a glitch? If you save while the light map baking is still in progress and then try to load the scene after the baking is done you somehow get the wrong key?

Comment: its an open issue that is being worked on i think. this is a workaround

Comment: I am able to reproduce this bug and will work on it. Looks like appcreator only uses the preview bake data3d model from the scene. For debugging I am using this scene: https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/archilogic/zmp3rqm6?modelResourceId=8b4c45e4-9f87-4911-a2da-9cac68fc66d6&mode=edit&view-menu=none&main-menu=lighting&logo=false It's less heavy content wise and hence easier to debug.

Comment: This will be solved with the new Scene API landing soon!

Comment: @Pandatology i think this has been fixed now? can we then close this issue here?

Comment: I've come across this issue too....is there a way to use the high-res bake with A-frame?
Archgilogic scene - https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/mark_lane/funclvdb?modelResourceId=18f610e3-eccd-48bc-aaa9-461b7879e497
Aframe scene - https://appcreator.3d.io/iQrBlG?m=nv